# Wrong path for external library in Play sub-project

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.3

I have a Play project with multiple sub-projects in folder *subprojects* in the root project. Everything is fine, until I try to import the project into eclipse, after performing *activator eclipse*:

When I import the root project, some errors occur, as this project obviously depends on the other (eclipsified) sub-projects.

Each of them has its own Eclipse project files (*.project* and *.classpath*) generated by the *activator eclipse* command. So trying to import these sub-projects as well fails if they contain unmanaged jar files in their *lib* folder, because the corresponding meta file *.classpath* of this sub-projects contains a relative classpath entry for those jar, which points to the wrong location, when imported as Eclipse project:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="../../subprojects/mod_service_a/lib/MyLib.jar"/>
```

Eclipse then won't find this lib after importing the project (no copy of contents)- it points two levels too high.

*Play Project Layout:*

- root

  - subprojects/mod_service_a
  - subprojects/mod_service_b

*Project Layout of imported Projects in Eclipse:*

- root
- mod_service_a
- mod_service_b

Any ideas how to solve this? How can I organize the Play sun-projects in eclipse, so that they can find their unmanaged jars in folder lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a really bad workaournd creating a soft-link to satisfy the wrong folder-lookup, I finally found a better solution: The TypeSafe SBT Eclipse Plugin provides an option to prevent creation of relative paths: just add this line to your corresponding sub-project's *build.sbt*

```
EclipseKeys.relativizeLibs := false
```

and you get absolute paths.

Generally absolute paths are not recommended, but in this case, it seems a working solution.

More information about the TypeSafe SBT Eclipse Plugin can be found here:
https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Using-sbteclipse